# Youtube API: Search endpoint with videoCaption not working

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

The following command works as expected:

```
GET https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?maxResults=1&q=test&key=[YOUR_API_KEY] HTTP/1.1

Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]
Accept: application/json
```

The following does not work as expected:

```
GET https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=1&q=test&videoCaption=closedCaption&key=[YOUR_API_KEY] HTTP/1.1

Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]
Accept: application/json
```

This is the full error:

```json
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "badRequest"
      }
    ],
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

This should work according to the documentation: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list

Could someone please help?

Best,
Andy

Comment: Strange this seems to work with python-youtube package but not through the webUI ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs state that for the videoCaption parameter you must set type to 'video' instead of the default 'video,channel,playlist'. This works:

[https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=1&q=test&videoCaption=closedCaption&type=video&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]](https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=1&q=test&videoCaption=closedCaption&type=video&key=%5BYOUR_API_KEY%5D)